# Bootstrap combining media query mixins

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm using Bootstrap 3 with Less and wondering if the below is the proper way to attach multiple media query mixins to a class? It seems to work, but I am unsure as I am still learning Less.

I normally just write in the differing css in their own breakpoint query at the bottom of my stylesheet. However, there are times when I need more granular control of things and I thought this might be a cleaner way to do it when using BS.

```
.title h1 {
text-align: center;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: 400;
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
   font-size: 40px;
   }   
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
   font-size: 40px;
   text-align: left;
   }  
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
   font-size: 50px;
   text-align: left;
   }
}
```

Comment: So if it works what does make you unsure? You can take a look at the Bootstrap source files to see they use exactly the [same method](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.2.0/less/grid.less#L10-L22). There *are* different methods ([E.G.](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature)), but if the question is "is it a proper way?" the answer is "Yes, it is".

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes just because I can get something to work doesn't mean it is the optimal way : ). So, because I don't use Less and mixin to classes, I just wanna make sure it is normal/good practice.

Comment: Also, in regards to the answer below, that is how I normally do it. The approach above may help me manage my tweaking better I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.title h1 {
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 30px;
   font-weight: 400;
}


@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
   .title h1 {
       font-size: 40px;
    }
}   
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
   .title h1 {
      font-size: 40px;
      text-align: left;
    }
}  
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
   .title h1 {
      font-size: 50px;
      text-align: left;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I normally do. My question was more about the different way I was describing above. I was thinking that it may be a cleaner approach to managing your stylesheet. Where Less is concerned I am still trying to figure out the most optimal way to do things.